# Using Jquery to Limit an input field from -100 to 100

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to limit a few input fields that would allow the user to input -100(min) and up to 100(max), while allow two decimal places. This one is tricky, so it should allow 99.99 but not allow 100.01. Also allow -99.99 but not -100.01, upon key-down it needs to remove what ever is wrong and prevent the user from entering an more characters If they hit -100 or 100 or -99.xx or 99.xx.

My code so far but is behaving very speraticly:

```
$(document).off('keyup keydown', 'input.NegativeHundredPercentMax');
$(document).on('keyup keydown', 'input.NegativeHundredPercentMax', function(e) {
  var $myInput = $(this);
  if ($myInput.val().length <= 4 ) {
     if ($myInput.val() <= -101) {
         e.preventDefault();
         $myInput.val($myInput.val().slice(0, 3));
     }
  } else {
     if ($myInput.val() <= -101) {
         e.preventDefault();
         $myInput.val($myInput.val().slice(0, 4));
     }
  }
});
```

Comment: why not use the input type number? that addresses both you issues

Comment: @epascarello to handle for the "-" sign

Comment: So what does not work with your code above? Seems like it is overly complicated and you are comparing strings to numbers.

Comment: @epascarello It allows for input of -100.xx, if i enter -99.98 and then delete out the decimal it will remove 1 character and present -999

Comment: Why so complicated? `if( Number($myInput.val()) < -100) { $myInput.val("-100") }`

Comment: You should reconsider doing it with html, because first you need to parse your val to integer, and before that make sure your user only types numbers (by using regexp), then do lots of compares, slices and what not to get a little close to what the other answers provided for you can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I corrected the issue by removing all complexity.

```
$(document).off('keyup keydown', 'input.NegativeHundredPercentMax');
$(document).on('keyup keydown', 'input.NegativeHundredPercentMax', function(e) {
    var $myInput = $(this);
    if ($myInput.val() < -100) {
        $myInput.val(-100);
    }
    if ($myInput.val() > 100) {
        $myInput.val(100);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 alone can handle an input which:

- takes only numbers
- has a minimum entry of `-100`
- has a maximum entry of `100`
- increments in 100ths

This will do it:

```
<input type="number" name="myNumber" min="-100" max="100" step="0.01" value="1" />
```

**Working Example:**

```html
<input type="number" name="myNumber" min="-100" max="100" step="0.01" value="1" />
```

Comment: This works thats correct, but it needs to be handled via JS and replicate able using a class.

Comment: The problem with `type="number"` fields is they still allow the `e` character to denote an exponent. You still need validation to cover that case as `e161e2149eeeee` is an allowed 'numerical' value, by the logic of the control only

Comment: Are you sure it's allowing `e`? It doesn't appear to be allowing `e` in Firefox 53.

Comment: @Rounin Yes is has to be replicated without changing the current html structure, i can add a class to the input, but it needs to remain a text. Our application is 1.5+ million lines of code, the HTML structure must remain the same.

Comment: So... can you update the markup dynamically like: `document.querySelector('[name="myNumber"]').setAttribute('type', 'number');` ?

Answer (score 0):

you can do that using HTML5 something like this should help

```html
<input type="number" name="quantity" min="-100" max="100" step="0.01">
```

Comment: I am aware you can do this with HTML, it needs to be done with JS

Comment: The problem with `type="number"` fields is they still allow the `e` character to denote an exponent. You still need validation to cover that case as `e161e2149eeeee` is an allowed 'numerical' value, by the logic of the control only